# Make: wildcard to match full path?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Using make for generic purposes** (not compiling)

Suppose I have a set of files with full path names, and I would like to do something with that file.

```
something --file a/b/c/X > $< # (for example)
```

And I have made a rule:

```
something-%:
    something --file $*
```

Which matches fine against, say, "something-foo" but does not catch "something-a/b/c/foo".  Is there a way to write a wildcard rule for this latter case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual describes [how patterns match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match):

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix.

In your case when calling as `make something-a/b/c/foo`, `something-a/b/c/` is treated as directory and removed, so the rest does not match your rule. This can be easily checked:

```
$ cat Makefile
something-%:
        echo something --file $<

f%o:
        echo $*
```

Output:

```
$ make something-OtherDirectory/src/foo -dr
GNU Make 4.2.1
...
Considering target file 'something-OtherDirectory/src/foo'.
 File 'something-OtherDirectory/src/foo' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'something-OtherDirectory/src/foo'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'o'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'something-OtherDirectory/src/foo'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'something-OtherDirectory/src/foo'.
Must remake target 'something-OtherDirectory/src/foo'.
echo something-OtherDirectory/src/o
...
```

Note that it matched the other pattern rule with the stem of `o`.

You can make it work your way if your pattern *does* include a slash. For sake of completeness I would also define a prerequisite if your rule is based on a file and declare target as phony if it does not generate a real output file:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: something/%
something/%: %
        echo something --file $<
```

Output:

```
$ make something/OtherDirectory/src/foo.c
echo something --file OtherDirectory/src/foo.c
something --file OtherDirectory/src/foo.c
```